# Getting data from two tables

Tags: linq

I have two tables in my database:

```
Employee(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeGroup)
Group(GroupID, GroupName, GroupLeader)
```

EmployeeGroup corresponds to GroupID
GroupLeader corresponds to EmployeeID

I want to select the columns:

```
EmpoyeeID, EmployeeName, LeaderName(Customer name)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var list = dataModel.Employee.Join( dataModel.Group, 
  e => e.EmployeeGroup, 
  g => g.GroupID, 
  (e, g) =>  
        new                                                                                         
              {
                 EmpoyeeID= e.EmpoyeeID, 
                 EmployyeName= e.EmployyeName, 
                LeaderName= g.GroupLeader.EmployyeName                
});
```